# Issue with TinyMce and Fontawesome icons on Moodle platform. Icons does not appear

Tags: tinymce, font-awesome, moodle

Since a long time we used Atto as text editor on Moodle.
On the footer we use fontawesome icons for social media links.
This is the code we mostly used with Atto.

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com" target="_blank" title="Facebook"><span class="sr-only">Linkedin</span><span class="fa-stack fa-lg"><span class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></span><span class="fa fa-linkedin fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></span></span></a>

    <a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank" title="Twitter"><span class="sr-only">twitter</span><span class="fa-stack fa-lg"><span class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></span><span class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></span></span></a>

    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank" title="Youtube"><span class="sr-only">Youtube</span><span class="fa-stack fa-lg"><span class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></span><span class="fa fa-youtube fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></span></span></a>
</div>
```

When we change to the TinyMce editor, the code is modified and the icons does not appear anymore.
The resulting code is :

```
<div style="text-align: center;"><a title="Twitter" href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><span class="sr-only">twitter</span></a> <a title="LinkedIn" href="https://www.linkedin.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><span class="sr-only">linkedin</span></a> <a title="Youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><span class="sr-only">Youtube</span></a></div>
```

All the fa classes are deleted and so the icons are not visible anymore.
What should i do to avoid this issue ?
We manage many Moodle platforms, and Atto editor won't be compatible with Moodle, soon.
So I do need to find a way to use this icons with TinyMce editor, on Moodle.

Thx for the help :)
Best regards,

Trying to use Font awesome icons with TinyMce editor, on a Moodle platform.

Comment: it's a bit late but did you find an answer ? I'm wondering why you're generating your footer with the text editor? Why not create one within your theme? This way you won't have any problem with your <i> from fontawesome.
Anyhow, you can use the code html editor within TinyMCE editor as for ATTO. Normally it shouldn't disappear.

Answer (score 1):

TinyMCE by default removes empty tags. You need put something inside the tag:

```
<i class="fa-solid fa-cubes-stacked">< !-- SOMETHING_HERE --> </i>
```

The same applies to `<em>`:

```
<em class="fa-regular fa-file-code"><!-- SOMETHING_HERE --></em>
```